# doxygen not resolving @ref references to members in same C# namespace

Tags: c#, doxygen, ref

First of all, I should say that I'm NOT a doxygen expert, and seem to learn some new trick or technique with every attempt to use it.  However, I have run into a situation where I am stumped about something that seems very fundamental, i.e. creating @ref's to methods.

To try to make sure I wasn't repeating something already reported, I searched for other examples of doxygen reporting "unable to resolve reference to" for \ref command, and found something similar to what I am seeing, but for C++.  That particular issue was supposedly fixed in doxygen 1.8.6.

However, the particular problem I am seeing is for C#.  I am also using doxygen 1.8.9.1.

I whittled things back to a shorter example, with one very simple mainpage.cs with a couple of @ref's to fully-qualified members within two simple C# classes.  Both classes are in the same namespace.  I don't know if it is germain or important, but the namespace actually has a compound name, i.e. XXX.Reader_Interface, instead of one simple name like ReaderInterface.

However, even if I fully qualify the method names with the namespace, I still end up with doxygen warnings:

C:/RefBug/Interface/mainpage.cs:26: warning: unable to resolve reference to `XXX.Reader_Interface.Reader.GetAvailableReaders()' for \ref command
C:/RefBug/Interface/mainpage.cs:31: warning: unable to resolve reference to`XXX.Reader_Interface.ReaderRef' for \ref command

My mainpage.cs:

```
/**
 * @file
 * 
 * @mainpage
 *
 * @tableofcontents
 *
 * @section intro  Introduction
 *
 * This document describes the Application Programming Interface (API) for
 * communicating with readers in the XXX Software system.

 * @section usingTheAPI Using the API
 *
 * This section describes a typical usage scenario for the API, along with the 
 * data sources and sinks and threads of execution.
 *
 * @subsection findingReaders   Finding Readers
 *
 * First, the application must be configured for (or figure out) what readers 
 * are available to be used by the system.  
 *
 * @subsubsection queryReaders Automatically Finding Readers
 *
 * One option to do this will be provided via the method 
 * @ref XXX.Reader_Interface.Reader.GetAvailableReaders() ,
 * which will use some kind of magic.  
 *
 * @subsubsection makeReader    Creating a Reader
 *
 * Instantiate a reader using a @ref XXX.Reader_Interface.ReaderRef.
 *
 * @defgroup abstractReader     What all Readers have in common
 */
```

One C# file, Reader.cs:

```
/**
 * 
 * @file
 * 
 * @brief      Brief description of file/module.
 * @details    More detailed description of file/module.
 * @copyright  (c) 2015 Somebody, Incorporated.  All rights reserved.
 * 
 */

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XXX.Instrument_Interface
{
    /// @ingroup abstractReader
    ///
    /// @brief  Abstract base class for a reader.
    ///
    /// <summary>
    /// Abstract base class to represent an reader with a serial interface.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class Reader
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Check each serial port to see if a reader is attached.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>
        /// Array of available readers.
        /// </returns>
        public static ReaderRef[] GetAvailableReaders()
        {
            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create an instance of a new reader, using an element of the list of 
        /// available readers as input.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reader">
        /// One of the readers found attached to this PC.
        /// Obtained from the list provided by GetAvailableReader().
        /// </param>
        public Reader(ReaderRef reader)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

The other C# file, ReaderRef.cs:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// 
/// @file
/// 
/// @brief      Brief description of file/module.
/// 
/// @details    More detailed description of file/module.
/// 
/// @copyright  (c) 2015 Somebody, Incorporated.  All rights reserved.
/// 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace XXX.Instrument_Interface
{
    /// @ingroup abstractReader
    ///
    /// @brief  Reference to a reader.
    ///
    /// <summary>
    /// Reference to an reader connected to this PC.
    /// </summary>
    public class ReaderRef
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the type of reader.
        /// </summary>
        public Type ReaderType
        {
            set;
            get;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a unique description for the reader.
        /// This should be unique to each reader, such as a serial number.
        /// </summary>
        public string Description
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets an instance of a specific reader based on the
        /// reader type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The reader if found, null otherwise.</returns>
        public Reader GetReader()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a bug, or am I somehow using doxygen in an incorrect manner?  I'm hoping that someone out there can tell me why doxygen is not able to resolve these references.  I would also be happy to upload a .zip file with this entire example for anyone who would like to try it out.

Thanks in advance for your help and patience!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this was a very simple, stupid mistake.  The reference I created did not match the namespace specifier, so of COURSE doxygen couldn't resolve it.  After stepping back and re-reviewing the code, I found it right away.  Sorry to have cluttered up the e-mail traffic, and thanks for your patience.